# Inductive limits of unitary groups and quantum mechanics

Tags: lie-groups, quantum-mechanics, limits-and-colimits

I'm curious if someone has seen concrete applications of $U(\infty)$ in quantum mechanics. Is it possible, for example, in some particular cases to write down the propagator as a limit of a sequence of propagators in finite dimensions?